# Why does these constructors have an error?

Tags: java

```
public class CharacterList {

    private char [] charArray;
    private int count;

    public CharacterList(int arraySize){

        charArray = new char[arraySize];
        count = 0;

    }
    

    private int indexOf(char searchingChar) {
        int a = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

            if(charArray[i] == searchingChar)
                a = i;

            else
                a = -1;
        }
        return a;

    }

    public boolean addCharacter(char characterToAdd){

        if(indexOf(characterToAdd) == -1){
            doubleArrayCapacity();
            count ++;
            return true;

        } else if(indexOf(characterToAdd) == 0){

            charArray[0] = characterToAdd;
            count++;
            return true;

        } else
            return false;


    }




}
```

I need to construct all the methods given in the attached list. I have done these many so far and the remaining are hard to get. Could someone:

1.) Check if the code I written till now is correct?
2.) Help me with the other constructors

Thank you in advance[image: This Image has the methods I would like to do]

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely distinct.

Comment: The primary problem would be that it's not valid JavaScript code

Comment: `i = a;` You probably meant `a = i;` there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ya I'm sorry Thanks. What about the code?

Comment: There is only one constructor. The others are normal methods.

Comment: The question would be much more readable if you copied the table into text. The image cannot be read out loud or enlarged easily. Sorry, but I have old eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE, it will tell you that line 31 and 32 are the errors:

```
c cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Fix:

Rename `c` to `characterToAdd`

```
The method doubleArrayCapacity() is undefined for the type CharacterList
```

Fix:

Create method doubleArrayCapacity()

```
private void doubleArrayCapacity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
```

And your code will compile (doesn't mean that it's working!).

Comment: I know we need to add a constructor. I don't really know the instructions under it though. Would be helpful if you could answer that

Answer (score 0):

Contructor is ok. Only one think I've found incorrect it your code is lack of method `public void doubleArrayCapacity()`. Probably you have forgoted implement or you avoid when copy source code here.
Another cause, where could be error is call of this contractor. How you call it? With argument or without? How that looks like?

```
 public void doubleArrayCapacity() {
    //create new array of char, which is double length
    char [] newCharArray = new char[this.charArray.length*2];
    //prescribe values from old array to new one
    for(int i=0; i<this.charArray.length-1; i++) {
        newCharArray[i] = this.charArray[i];
    }
    //set newCharArray set new value of your field charArray
    this.charArray = newCharArray;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure of what should be the instructions under public void doubleArrayCapacity()

Comment: I have added example of this implementation. You need create new array as variable with double length, then prescribe values from old array into new and on the end set new array as field value

Comment: Thank you I understood! Could you please help me with the other methods. Most importantly, How do we find if the capacity of the array is full or not